# Join unrelated table with unequal rows

Tags: sql, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I would like to join Table A, Table B, and Table C as the expected result in the attached image.

[image: Image Link]

Comment: You are not looking for a `CROSS JOIN`.  So what you want to accomplish is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows and use that for joining . . . which might be what you want:

```
select ab.*, c.*
from (select a.*, b.*,   -- really list out the columns you want
             row_number() over (order by accountid) as seqnum
      from a join
           b
           on a.accountid = b.accountid
     ) ab join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by code) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
     on ab.seqnum = c.seqnum
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, 
Thank you very much, it helps a lot!

adding JOIN to your sample code would work perfectly.

select ab.*, c.*
from (select a.*, b.*,   -- really list out the columns you want
             row_number() over (order by accountid) as seqnum
      from a join
           b
           on a.accountid = b.accountid
     ) ab
     JOIN
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by code) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
     on ab.seqnum = c.seqnum